# Event on Keystone JS view not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, keystonejs

I'm doing an e-commerce site (learning purposes) with KeystoneJS. In the view where I display all the products I want to add a filter for sort the items by price and another one to show the products of only one brand. Two forms are needed but I don't get to submit only one

My products.pug looks like this

```
.container
  form(method='post')
    input(type='hidden', name='action', value='products')
    button(type='submit').btn.btn-primary Send
```

And my products.js in routes/views/ looks like this

```
[...]
// Print a word when submit the form
view.on('post', { action: 'products' }, function(next) {
  console.log('POST')
  next()
})
// Get all products from db
view.on('init'...)
// Render
view.render('products')
```

So basically what I want to do is to print **POST** when I hit the button in the view. Instead of that, I receive a 404 error page. I would really appreciate if you guys can help me

Comment: I should add that if i change the method in the form and the verb in the event to GET and delete the second parameter it prints the word. Why doesn't it work with method post?

Comment: This looks correct. Did you try making your form method `POST` instead of `post`?

Comment: Yes, and keeps going wrong. I have chosen to use method GET and place all in only one form but I really want to solve this because, as you said, it seems right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! In /routes/index.js I replaced

```
app.get('/products', route.views.products);
```

for

```
app.all('/products', route.views.products);
```

I feel dummy but happy.

Comment: Finally I got it as well. Thanks to you. I had different input fields in one page and that might have caused the trouble. Any idea why we need this hidden input in the form `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact">`  ?

Comment: Glad I helped you! About the inputs: I guess this is only necessary if you are making different POST requests (multiple forms) and these are handled by the same route, so for every request you have a different `input:hidden` with a specific value and action. At least, it's what I do and I haven't had any issue so far.